# Xcodebuild target without today and watch extension

Tags: ios, xcode, watch, xcodebuild, today-extension

My project contain four targets, they are

- MainTarget
- TodayTarget
- WatchTarget
- WatchExtensionTarget

I had try to specific build target to `MainTarget` only by `xcodebuild` command ,but the Today Target and Watch also would built because main target's Build Phases add Embed App extension and Embed Watch Content
[image]

Are there any way to achieve this？

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry, I read your question completely wrong..
You if your `MainTarget` depends upon your other targets for the Watch App and Today Widget then you cannot exclude them when building.

If however, you want to remove the Watch App and Today Widget then you could try removing them from the "Target Dependencies" build phase (top of your screen shot) and then also remove the two build phases at the bottom that you have highlighted.

This does however mean that you've removed it completely from your app target and you would have to add it back in again if you want them back.

---

### Old Answer (with wrong understanding)

You should be able to build the `MainTarget` via `xcodebuild` without any issues because the Today Extension/Watch Targets should be in the "Target Dependancies" section up top..

You should be able to use something like the following:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ".//MyProject.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyMainTargetSceme"  -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -configuration "Release" -derivedDataPath "DerivedData" clean archive -archivePath "builds/87/MyProject-Release/MyProject-Release-87.xcarchive"
```

to produce an .xcarchive that can be used to export the application at a later date...

You can then also export that archive to a valid .ipa using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "builds/87/MyProject-Release/MyProject-Release-87.xcarchive" -exportPath "builds/87/MyProject-Release" -exportOptionsPlist "ipa_export_options.plist"
```

And a basic export options plist can look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>same-as-archive</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The available keys/values for your plist can be seen by running the `xcodebuild --help` command.

Comment: I am thinking of duplicate the MainTarget ,and remove Extension and Watch on the duplicated target , But what I am concern is when MainTarget changes Build Setting, I have to synchronize it for new target.

Comment: You are correct... Duplicating the main target might be a bit of a pain in the backside... Can i ask why you might want to sometimes build without and sometimes build with the watch/extensions? There might be a better solution available

Comment: When our app deliver to App Store, I want to build a archive with the watch/extensions. But when I deliver our app to our test user, who has a jailbreak iPhone, I want to build without watch/extension, because we just want to test the new feature on MainTarget, and deliver a target with group capacity open will cause their phone crash.

Comment: I know its off topic of the original question but it seems a little excessive just to enable a beta tester to use your app. Testing the app is something you usually want to do with the exact same version that you're going to be rolling out to the public but this would not be the case in your situation. I guess you are going to have to duplicate your `MainTarget` then make sure you keep it in sync. It shouldn't be _too_ much of an issue, just make sure that you try to keep as may settings configured at a project level (rather than a target level) so that they're shared across targets